# File upload control in Sitecore Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using `Sitecore 9 Forms` and I am creating `file upload control` in Forms, for this, I have created FileUpload file type.

```
 [Serializable]
public class FileUploadViewModel: InputViewModel<HttpPostedFileBase>
{

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public override HttpPostedFileBase Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
    {          
        base.InitItemProperties(item);       
    }
    protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
    {
      base.UpdateItemFields(item);
    }

}
```

also created `FileUpload.cshtml`

```
@model Sitecore.Foundation.Forms.Custom.Fields.FileUploadViewModel 
<input type="file" value="@Model.Value" />
```

and created one submit action, but I am getting null in Value field. Please provide me some guidance.

**Updated jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your file is not coming through is because the form is sent over ajax and is not using the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

This is caused by the script

```
<script src="/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

loaded via `@Html.RenderFormScripts()`

More info on this script can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643512/upload-is-null-after-adding-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-js-reference

**There are 2 options:**

- use an `asynchronous upload via ajax`
- or modify the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script.

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is not working. It is showing error message "options.data.push is not a function"

Comment: Added image above

Comment: I have created a extension library for the sitecore forms containing a file upload control. https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions. You can find my version of the javascript-file modification you require here: https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/blob/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: take a look at the lines 112 to 121, you need to build the options differently when posting the multipart instead of json